# how Symbolicate a crash file using xcarchive

Tags: ios, symbolicatecrash

I've found this good tutorial: https://www.apteligent.com/technical-resource/symbolicating-an-ios-crash-report/

After read it I understand that I have to use the crash file and the xcarchive/pathtodsymfile to Symbolicate the crash file because my IPA is not in the appstore, is just an adhoc IPA.

I've located the file: myapp.xcarchive/dSYMs/myapp.app.dSYM

Then I use the following command:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/SharedFrameworks/DVTFoundation.framework/Versions/A/Resources/symbolicatecrash -v my.crash myapp.xcarchive/dSYMs/myapp.app.dSYM > results.txt
```

And this is the output:

```
Num stacks found: 13
0 binary images remain after pruning:

($hwModel, $osVersion, $osBuild) = (iPhone9?4, 12.2, 16E227)
$versionPattern = {iPhone9?4 12.2 (16E227),iPhone9?4 12.2 (16E227) *,12.2 (16E227),12.2 (16E227) *,12.2,16E227,16E227 *}
Symbol directory paths:  /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.2 (16E227)/Symbols /Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport/12.2 (16E227) arm64e/Symbols
Finding Symbols:
0 binary images were found.
No symbolic information found
```

And the results.txt file is the same of my.crash

What I'm doing wrong?

my.crash file https://gist.github.com/rchampa/7d162aab64f0d21f594a8188bf00fac1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out that my logs was `__hidden` so I've just 
set `Build Settings -> Enable bitcode to No` and then there is not need to symbolicate.